# Proof of Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ Law in Shiryaev

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know this theorem has been discussed in a lot of posts on this site however I was unable to find an answer that deals with the particular proof I am trying to understand. I'm interested in the proof of Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law given in the book "*Probability by Albert Shiryaev*". The statement is as follows,

**Theorem:**
Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent random variables and let $A \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n^{\infty}$, i.e an element of the tail $\sigma$-algebra. Then $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ or $1$.

We define $\mathcal{F}_n^k = \sigma(\xi_n,\xi_{n+1},\ldots,\xi_{k})$ with the convention $\mathcal{F}_n^{\infty}=\sigma(\xi_n,\xi_{n+1},\ldots)$.

**Proof:**
Clearly we have $A \in \mathcal{F}_1^\infty=\sigma(\xi_1,\xi_{2},\ldots)=\sigma(\cup_n \mathcal{F}_1^n)$. We can find sets $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_1^n$, $m\geq1$, such that $\mathbb{P}(A \Delta A_n) \to 0$ as  $n \to \infty$. Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(A_n) \to \mathbb{P}(A), \quad \mathbb{P}(A_n \cap A) \to \mathbb{P}(A) .$$

But as $A \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n^{\infty}$, the events $A_n$ and $A$ are independent for every $n \geq 1$. Hence it follows that $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A)^2$, which completes the proof.

Now first of all I presume the $m$ is a typo and this should be an $n$. The only issue I'm having with this proof is the claim that you can approximate the event $A$ by an event in $\mathcal{F}_1^n$, and by approximate I mean in the sense of the pseudo metric defined by the symmetric difference operation.

Shiryaev has an exercise in a previous chapter which he refers to in this proof that says given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{F}$, for any $B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that,

$$\mathbb{P}(B \Delta A) \leq \epsilon. $$

In the proof above the set in which we are taking the $A_n$'s are one, not necessarily an algebra as unions of $\sigma$-algebras need not be an algebra and secondly they do not even generate the $\sigma$-algebra that $A$ belongs to, i.e $\mathcal{F}_1^\infty$. So my question is why we can apply this result ?

Just to be 100% clear the proof is transcribed correctly, i.e the possible typo of $m\geq1$ does appear in the book.

Comment: $\bigcup_{n}F_{1}^{n}$ is an algebra.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes this is a detail I have missed. However what this allows us to claim is for any $\epsilon$ we can find a set $A_\epsilon \in \cup_n \mathcal{F}_1^n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A \Delta A_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon$. So say we choose $\epsilon = 1/n$, then the proof is stating we can always find an $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_1^n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A \Delta A_n) \leq 1/n$. But we have no right to say that the set $A_n$ is a member of $\mathcal{F}_1^n$, we can only claim it is a member of the union of all the $\mathcal{F}_1^n$'s.

Comment: You are correct. We obtain $A_n \in F_{m(n)}$. But we can pad the sequence by adding copies of some elements to obtain a sequence with $B_n \in F_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by @Mason I believe I have figured out the problem. We are free to say that $\cup_n \mathcal{F}_1^n$ is an algebra as it is an increasing union of $\sigma$-algebras. Thus the density result can be applied. However as I outlined in my comment the problem is now in claiming that each $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_1^n$. The density result only tells us that there exists some set in $\cup_n \mathcal{F}_1^n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A\Delta A_n) \leq \epsilon_n$.

This can be answered in the following way. Originally I assumed that the $m$ that appeared in the proof was a typo, I know believe this is not the case. In fact I think the typo is that the line,

"We can find sets $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_1^n$, $m \geq 1$, such that $\mathbb{P}(A \Delta A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$."

Should actually read,

We can find sets $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_1^m$, $m \geq 1$, such that $\mathbb{P}(A \Delta A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The difference being that each $A_n$ is a member of $\mathcal{F}_1^m$ for some $m$ which is the same as saying $A_n \in \cup_n \mathcal{F}_1^n$. The main point is that with this statement we are not claiming to know exactly which $\sigma$-algebra these sets $A_n$ belong to, we only know they must belong to one of them.

However any time I need to claim that there is typo in a very well respected book in order for me to understand the proof, it usually means that I just completely misunderstood the argument in the first place! Hence any opinions on my analysis would be very much appreciated.